# What command do I use to locate this element?

Tags: python, selenium

The source HTML code is as follows:

```
<p class="style protect" itemprop="model">Red</p>
```

How can I get selenium to search for "Red" when it isn't named? I have tried using

```
browser.find_element_by_name('Red')
```

and a lot of other commands (`find_element_by_link_text`...) but I cannot find the correct one to use to find a click the word "Red". Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to locate element by its text content you might use below XPath:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[.='Red']")
```

Note that `find_element_by_name()` intend to get `name` attribute as argument, e.g. `<p name="Red">...<p>`, `find_element_by_link_text()` applicable for links only, e.g. `<a href="/red">Red</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Using [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('p[itemprop=model]')
```

Comment: How can I make sure that it's red though? I need for the color to be red.

Comment: @Andersson 's answer is better